# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 0 defaultTableModel Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, defaulttablemodel

I would like to save and display data from database in JTable, and tried to use defaultTableModel for that. However, I'm getting:

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at com.mycompany.bazadanych.main.main(main.java:40) (line with ** **).
```

Is there a method to predefine count of columns/rows in JTable and simply pass data to them?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     bazaDanych BazaDanych = new bazaDanych();
     DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
     JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
     tableModel.setColumnCount(3);


 try {
     //BazaDanych.wstawDane("STUDENCI", "Kowalski", "Jan");
     //BazaDanych.wstawDane("STUDENCI", "Wiśniewski", "Piotr");
     //BazaDanych.wstawDane("STUDENCI", "Nowak", "Michał");
     BazaDanych.usunDane("STUDENCI", "Nowak", "Michał");
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }

 List<Student> lista = BazaDanych.pobierzDane("STUDENCI");
      BazaDanych.zamknijPolaczenie();
 lista.forEach(s -> {
    **table.setValueAt(s.getId(), s.getId(), 0);**
    table.setValueAt(s.getNazwisko(), s.getId(), 1);
     table.setValueAt(s.getImie(), s.getId(), 2);
     //tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {s.getId(),  s.getNazwisko(), s.getImie()});
     System.out.println(s.getId() + " " + s.getNazwisko() + " " + s.getImie());
 });
  table.updateUI();
 //stable.setModel(tableModel);
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo program for JFrame");
 frame.setLayout(null);
 frame.add(table);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

     frame.pack();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a method to predefine count of columns/rows in JTable and simply pass data to them?

How do you know what the predefined size of the table should be?

Your data is contained in a List of Students. The better approach would be to:

1. Create a custom `StudentTableModel`. Then there is no need for the forEach loop. You just create the model using the `List<Student>`. See [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step-by-step example on how to create a custom model.
2. Use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` as indicated in your code. This means you need to get rid of the `setValueAt(...)` statements.

Other issues with the code:

1. Don't use updateUI(). Swing components will auotmatically repaint themselves when the model is updated.
2. Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.
3. Typically a JTable is used with a JScrollPane and the scroll pane is added to the frame.